Column resize in table intefering all columns sizes
I have an Angular table component utilizing the <table> tag. The columns in the table utilize a directive for resizing their widths. The issue arises when I resize a column, as the width of nearly all other columns is affected. It appears that the table is imposing width constraints in the columns. Intead, I would like it to keep the columns widths intact, and resize itself if needed (it already has a horizontal scroll, but only appears when the columns are no fiting in the screen).
My component template:
<div
  class="table-container"
  class="{{ theme }}"
  [class.without-upper-border]="removeHeaderBorder"
>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="table" *ngIf="data" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th
          class="header-cell"
          *ngFor="let col of columns"
          [ngStyle]="{ width: '150px' }"
          appResizableColumn
        >
          {{ col.label }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr
        class="row"
        *ngFor="let row of displayedRows; let rowIndex = index"
        [class.highlight]="rowIndex + 1 | isEven"
        (contextmenu)="showRowContextMenu($event, rowIndex)"
      >
        <td
          class="row-cell"
          *ngFor="let col of columns"
          (dblclick)="onCellSelection(rowIndex, col.attributeName)"
        >
          <ng-container
            *ngIf="row[col.attributeName].editing; else elseTemplate"
          >
            <app-table-cell-input
              class="cell-input"
              [cell]="row[col.attributeName]"
              (clickOutside)="onCellBlur(rowIndex, col.attributeName)"
              (valueChanged)="
                onCellValueChange(rowIndex, col.attributeName, $event)
              "
            ></app-table-cell-input>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #elseTemplate>
            <span class="text">
              {{ row[col.attributeName].value || "" | square }}</span
            >
          </ng-template>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <app-pagination-list
    [items]="rowsSyncCopy"
    (displayedItemsChanges)="updateDisplayedRows($event)"
  ></app-pagination-list>
</div>

My directive:
@Directive({
  selector: '[appResizableColumn]',
})
export class ResizableColumnDirective {
  startX: number = 0;
  startWidth: number = 0;
  resizeHandleWidth: number = 10;
  isResizing: boolean = false;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    const mouseX = event.pageX;
    const rect = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rightEdge = rect.right;

    if (rightEdge - mouseX <= this.resizeHandleWidth) {
      this.startX = event.pageX;
      this.startWidth = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
      this.isResizing = true;

      this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'resizing');
      this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'resizing');

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onBorderDrag.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp.bind(this));
    }
  }

  onBorderDrag(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isResizing) {
      const newWidth = this.startWidth + (event.clientX - this.startX);
      this.renderer.setStyle(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement,
        'width',
        newWidth + 'px'
      );
    }
  }

  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isResizing) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp.bind(this));

      this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'resizing');
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'resizing');

      this.isResizing = false;
    }
  }
}

My component scss:
.table-container {
  color: color(grey-600);
  border-radius: space(1);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  &.without-upper-border {
    border-radius: 0 0 space(1) space(1);
  }

  .table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  .table {
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }

  .header-cell,
  .row-cell {
    border-top: 1px solid color(grey-200);
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .header-cell {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: space(2);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: color(grey-900);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;

    &:last-child {
      border-right-style: none;
    }

    &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 1px;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.2s all;
    }

    &.near-right-border {
      &::after {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      cursor: col-resize !important;
    }
  }

  .row {
    transition: 0.2s all;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: transparent;

    &:hover {
      background-color: color(blue-50);
    }

    &:active {
      background-color: color(blue-100);
    }

    &:last-child {
      .row-cell:first-child {
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      .row-cell:last-child {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }

    .row-cell {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      max-width: 15rem;
      background-color: transparent; // Background transparente

      &:last-child {
        border-right-style: none;
      }

      .text {
        padding: space(1);
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .cell-input {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    }
  }

